# Using Flask-sqlalchemy, how to sort data using order_by with some avarage data which is need to join?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy to control Mysql as ORM.
Here is my simple database graph
[simple graph about database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFu4P.png)

Problem is that I am supposed to make a user list. Gonna sort each user based on the avarage star of reviews which can be found and calculated in many levels depth

So I made some codes:

```
UserModel.query\
    .group_by(UserModel.id) \
    .join(UserServiceModel,UserModel.id == UserServiceModel.user_id) \
    .join(BookModel,UserServiceModel.id == BookModel.user_service_id) \
    .join(ReviewModel,BookModel.id == ReviewModel.book_id) \
    .with_entities(func.avg(ReviewModel.star)) \
    .all()
```

It seems the problem has been solved, almost, but those users who have no books or reviews are not in the list after I used JOIN.

Question is , how can I sort all users by avarage stars even most of them have no review records, I need all users in the list no matter avarage is 0 or None.

Otherwise, is there any other good idea to do this?

Comment: You need a LEFT JOIN, or `outerjoin()` in SQLAlchemy parlance. Note that when asking SQLA questions leaving your models out of the question is... out of the question. They're decipherable from your code, but that's one extra hoop to jump through. The model code is also usually more useful than a DB graph image.

Comment: Thanks for your Note and outerjoin() works for me, just need to change None to 0.0

Comment: If you're looking for how to handle that NULL produced by the left join, then use the COALESCE function in SQL: `func.coalesce(func.avg(ReviewModel.star), 0.0)`.

Comment: func.coalesce() works very well, it is from SQL "SELECT COALESCE()". Learn a lot from you,Thanks. And could you add an answer so I can choose yours as best.